# while checking the command pip freeze, the segmentation fault error is showing

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv

I am trying to install a virtual env. for python django.
when I try `pip freeze` to check django version it says "segmentation fault core dumped"

while using `pip install django` command its giving the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually ans is simple, it needs admin rights, so use `sudo pip install django`